# Динамическое генерирование кнопок в Telegram BOT на aiogram из Google Sheets

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, google-spreadsheet

**Доброго времени суток.**
Делаю телеграм бота на базе aiogram. Небольшой проект, в качестве БД используеться Google Sheets.
Бот для учёта сдачи/аренды велосипедов, некоторые сдаються, некоторые свободны. Уже несколько дней бьюсь на проблемой, нужно создать Inline клавиатуру, которая бы парсила таблицу и отображала только кнопки со свободными велосипедами. Перепробовал многое, но ничего не подходит.

Не прошу делать работу за меня, а лишь направить на верный путь к решению вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос, по сути, никакого отношения к Telegram-ботам не имеет, и вот почему:

Во-первых, клавиатура не может ничего парсить. Клавиатура - это обычный массив из кнопок `InlineKeyboardButton`. Как Вы зададите ей вид, так она и будет выглядеть. Парсить должна именно Ваша программа, на выходе вы составляете этот самый готовый массив, и передаёте клавиатуру в Ваше сообщение.

Во-вторых, для того, чтобы парсить и работать с Google-таблицами, Вам поможет официальная API документация ([Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)).

Можете сами написать Вашу обёртку для API, а можете обратить внимание на готовые библиотеки. Вот например несколько из них

- https://github.com/burnash/gspread
- https://github.com/xflr6/gsheets
- https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets